# Java random values and duplicates

Tags: java, random, duplicates

I have an array (`cards`) of 52 cards (13x4), and another array (`cardsOut`) of 25 cards (5x5). I want to copy elements from the 52 cards into the 25 card array by random.

Also, I dont want any duplicates in the 5x5 array. So here's what I have:

```
        double row=Math.random() *13;
        double column=Math.random() *4;

        boolean[][] duplicates=new boolean[13][4];

        pokerGame[][] cardsOut = new pokerGame[5][5];
        for (int i=0;i<5;i++)
            for (int j=0;j<5;j++){
                if(duplicates[(int)row][(int)column]==false){
                    cardsOut[i][j]=cards[(int)row][(int)column];
                    duplicates[(int)row][(int)column]=true;
                }
            }
```

2 problems in this code. First, the random values for row and column are only generated once, so the same value is copied into the 5x5 array every time. Since the same values are being copied every time, I'm not sure if my duplicate checker is very effective, or if it works at all.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd recommend [shuffling](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List%29) the deck in place first, then selecting the first 25 cards to place in your 5x5 array. Trying to mix these two steps is unnecessary complication.

If you need to optimize for performance (you probably don't) then it is worth noting that you can use the [Fisher-Yates shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) and stop the algorithm after the first 25 random cards have been selected without shuffling the remaining cards.

Comment: Hmm well if that's the case then I guess I could use the built in Collections.shuffle right?

Comment: @f-Prime: Yes that would be fine, as long as its OK that it shuffles all the cards, not just the first 25. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Ok thanks. But now, in general, disregarding the duplicate aspect, how would I generate new random numbers every iteration?

Comment: @f-Prime: If you use the `Collections.shuffle` method then it should just work. And you shouldn't need to worry about duplicates either because shuffling won't give duplicates - it just reorders the cards.

Answer (score 5):

I think your approach makes it more difficult than it should be.  Try using a class named card, and two collections - one named CardsRemaining and another named CardsUsed.

Initially, CardsRemaining contains all 52 card objects, and CardsUsed is empty.  As cards are added to CardsUsed, they are removed from CardsRemaining, naturally preventing duplicates from occuring.

Your program might end up looking something like this (sorry it's in c#):

```
  class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Card> CardsRemaining=new List<Card>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
                {
                    Card c = new Card(i, j);
                    CardsRemaining.Add(c);
                }
            }
            List<Card> CardsUsed = new List<Card>();
            for(int i=0;i<25;i++)
            {
                int cardIndex = getRandomNumber(CardsRemaining.Count);
                Card c = CardsRemaining[cardIndex];
                CardsRemaining.Remove(c);
                CardsUsed.Add(c);
            }
        }
    }

    class Card
    {
        public int Number;
        public int Color;
        public Card(int number, int color)
        {
            this.Number = number;
            this.Color = color;
        }
    }
```